# Why doesn't sublime automatically detect this custom sublime-build with a selector?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-build

I have the following saved to `node-sass.sublime-build` in my User folder

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "node-sass.cmd $file",
    "selector": "source.scss"
}
```

I have a `slideEditor.scss` file. If I explicitly set the build system to `node-sass`, ctrl+b works just fine, but if I set it to "Automatic", ctrl+b does nothing with nothing being logged to the console. What can be going on? According [the limited documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) I'm doing everything correct.

Comment: What package are you using for syntax highlighting? It's possible that the base scope is not `source.scss`.

Comment: @MattDMo interesting, I'm not sure what you mean by that? I'm using [the Sass package](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Sass). I've never heard of the concept of "base scope". The documentation on sublime lead me to think `source` was basically a wildcard for a file name, is that not true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the short answer to your question: change `"source.scss"` to `"source.sass"` and the Automatic build system should work fine.

The background, and some alternatives:

Syntax highlighting in Sublime (and TextMate, where the idea originally came from) is based on `.tmLanguage` syntax definitions for each language. These XML/Plist files are basically a series of regexes that assign their matches to scopes. For example, in the following CSS:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

the word `body` has the scope `source.css meta.selector.css entity.name.tag.css`. `source.css` is the *base scope*, or the parent for all other scopes. In a Python file, the base scope would be `source.python`, in HTML it's `text.html.basic`, Javascript is `source.javascript`, etc. This base scope is what the `"selector"` is looking for - it has nothing to do with the file name.

The syntax definition you're using has a base scope of [`source.sass`](https://github.com/nathos/sass-textmate-bundle/blob/master/Syntaxes/Sass.tmLanguage#L402), which is why your build system wasn't working unless you specifically selected it (which overrides the `selector` attribute). There are two ways around this. The first, as I mentioned above, is to simply change the selector to `source.sass`, and you'll be all set. The second, which I prefer, is to use the [Syntax Highlighting for Sass](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Syntax%20Highlighting%20for%20Sass) package, available from Package Control. For one thing, it has separate language definitions for SASS and SCSS, so you can get proper highlighting for both. The base scope for SCSS is `source.scss`, as you'd expect, while for SASS it's `source.sass`, so you can have separate build systems if you're using both languages. Additionally, the syntax definition is much richer than the package you're using, so if you're using one of the [recommended color schemes](https://github.com/P233/Syntax-highlighting-for-Sass#recommended-color-schemes) you'll get very nice highlighting of all the various elements, keywords, properties, etc. Finally, the package includes a bunch of completions and other extras that make writing stylesheets much easier.