# Why doesn't sublime automatically detect this matlab custom sublime-build with a selector?

Tags: matlab, sublimetext, sublimetext3

This question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370024/why-doesnt-sublime-automatically-detect-this-custom-sublime-build-with-a-select).

I have set up this matlab custom build in Sublime Text 3, according to this [github repository](https://github.com/jessebikman/Sublime-Text-2-build-Matlab-code):

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/matlab", "-nosplash", "<$file_name"],
    "selector": "source.m"
}
```

But if the build system is set to *automatic*, after pressing `Ctrl + b`, Sublime Text says *No Build System*.
Is there something wrong with the selector?

> `selector`
> If the **Tools | Build System | Automatic** option is set, Sublime Text will automatically find the corresponding build system for the active file by matching `selector` to the file's scope.

-- https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/usage/build-systems.html

Answer (score 0):

You may try to change the selector from "source.m" to "source.matlab", based on [the example](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/usage/build-systems.html).